# retaining the precison after reading and writing the double values to binary file

Tags: c#

I am creating a binary file. the contents of the files are double values.
When I extract the double values using a binary reader, some values after the decimal points are not matching

For ex:
the value written to a file.
-0.0139519833028316

Value extracted from a file.
-0.0139519833028317

How I can avoid this kind of inconsistency?

```
aStreamWriter.WriteLine(double values);

//to read the data ,
BinaryReader aBinaryReader = new BinaryReader();
int points_length = CurveCount * VectorLength * 2 * VoxelIndex.Length * 2;
double[] points = new double[points_length];
for (int i = 0; i < points_length; i++)
    points[i] = aBinaryReader.ReadDouble();
for(int i =0; i < points_length; i++) {
    // then write the points values to a file
}
```

Comment: How did you read and write. *Exactly*. And how did you *compare*. Not all numbers can be represented exactly in a double.

Comment: StreamWriter aStreamWriter = new StreamWriter();

Comment: There is no such constructor, and that doesn't show how you wrote and read the values.

Comment: Also, your line `aBinaryReader  = new BinaryReader()` makes no sense - no such constructor there either. It is very likely that your attempt to anonymise the code has made it impossible to get a sensible answer.

Answer (score 0):

Is it truly an inconsistency? double is conceptually an aproximation to a real number. Is that digit significant given the error in the original measurement? Are they not truly the "same" number in this context?

Answer (score 0):

Edit:

with your comment, the problem becomes obvious. `StreamWriter` is a **text writer**. The call to `aStreamWriter.WriteLine(double)` is writing **text**. Frankly, you were lucky to get anything back **at all**.

---

Original

Works fine:

```
    double d = -0.0139519833028316;
    byte[] raw;
    using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
    {
        using (var writer = new BinaryWriter(ms))
        {
            writer.Write(d);
        }
        raw = ms.ToArray();
    }
    double newVal;
    using(var ms = new MemoryStream(raw))
    using (var reader = new BinaryReader(ms))
    {
        newVal = reader.ReadDouble();
    }
    Console.WriteLine(newVal == d); // True
```

I suspect you're just seeing `double` rounding oddities, that are completely unrelated to the read/write code.

Comment: only few values in the array are not matching.

Comment: @Raghav55 see my edit: frankly what you have is gibberish - you can't write with `StreamWriter` and read with `BinaryReader`. That makes precisely zero sense.

Comment: so how to do the comparsion, without dumping back the values to a file. Is it better to save the values as a runtime value and compare?

Comment: @Raghav55 who mentioned comparison? The point is: if you are going to read with `BinaryReader`, you need to write with `BinaryWriter`. Not `StreamWriter`, which is a **text** writer (it is a subclass of `TextWriter`).

Comment: sorry there was little confusion, the values are written and read using a binary writer and binary reader. Before writing the values to a file using the binary writer , I am dumping the values using the stream writer.

Comment: m_BinaryWriter.Write(double); m_StreamWriter.WriteLine(double);

Comment: @Raghav55 right; go back and edit the question, and put in some **actual** code that shows what you are **actually** doing, and **actually** seeing. Until then, you are *wasting people's time*. Ideally, the sample should be minimal and complete - see the code at the end of my answer: you can *just run it* - that is what the code in the question should be like: complete enough to execute and show the problem. Also: your comment directly above makes no sense and does not explain anything.

Answer (score 0):

Basicly you have a problem with a double data type. Double is basicly making an aproximation of a number with a base of 2 (2^64). If there isnt an EXACT number that can be calculated (from base 10) then it picks closes number there is that can be saved as double.

If you need super precise way to save some number, save it as a string. Depend on math or what ever you need to do with a number, you can always write your own functions.

Simmilar stuff is happening with saving 'money value' as float in DB. they use money datatype due float isn't really a way to go.